# The wait operation timed out in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I have a table contains **100 columns and 2,000,000 records**.

When I am fetching records using stored procedure from that sometimes I am getting **"The wait operation timed out." error**.When I alter the stored procedure and try to fetch the records, it works fine.

Can anyone let me know what is the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vishal Naik has mentioned, SQL server has a default query timeout setting of 30 seconds. A possible solution would be to manually increase this time for a given query and this, while not recommended, should be effective. The code is as follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 60; // or any other length of time in seconds
/*Any other properties to be modified in the command will come here*/
SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: @YogeshKhurpe unfortunately, you cannot change the CommandTimeout property from configuration.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server has default query timeout setting of 30 seconds.

For more details [click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/915849/error-message-when-you-try-to-modify-a-large-table-by-using-sql-server-management-studio-timeout-expired)